# How to reset plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

How to reset values when switching slides?
https://jsfiddle.net/j6u6wp7x/

```
var scene;
var controller;
$(document).ready(function() {
    parallaxAuto();

    $(".right_arrr").click(function(){
        var block = $(this).siblings('.secondSlider');
        el = block.find(".active");
        elNum = el.attr("data-num");
        if(elNum < block.find('.slide').length) {
            elNum++;
        } else {
            elNum=1;
        }
        hideShow(elNum, block);
        alert('slide №' + elNum)
        scene = scene.destroy(true);
        scene = null;
        controller.destroy(true);
        controller = null;
        parallaxAuto();
    });
    $(".left_arrr").click(function(){
        var block = $(this).siblings('.secondSlider');
        el = block.find(".active");
        elNum = el.attr("data-num");
        if(elNum > 1) {
            elNum--;
        } else {
            elNum=block.find('.slide').length;
        }
        hideShow(elNum, block);
        scene = scene.destroy(true);
        scene = null;
        controller.destroy(true);
        controller = null;
        parallaxAuto();
    });
});

function hideShow(num, block) {
  block.find("div.active").removeClass("active").animate({ opacity: 0,},300);
  block.find("div.slide"+num).addClass("active").animate({ opacity: 1,},300);
}
// init variables
function parallaxAuto() {
    var viewer       = document.querySelector('.viewer.active'),
    frame_count  = 5,
    offset_value = 500;

    // init controller
    controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: 0,
        reverse: true
      }
    });

    // build pinned scene
    scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#sticky',
      duration: (frame_count * offset_value) + 'px',
      reverse: true
    })
    .setPin('#sticky')
    //.addIndicators()
    .addTo(controller);

    // build step frame scene
    for (var i = 1, l = frame_count; i <= l; i++) {
      new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: '#sticky',
          offset: i * offset_value
        })
        .setClassToggle(viewer, 'frame' + i)
        //.addIndicators()
        .addTo(controller);
    }
}
```

You can see in the example that the transition to the next slide stored value
And it is necessary that when we switch the values updated. I can not achieve this effect